# How can I make an absolute element sticky using CSS?

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have the following sidebar nav panel:

[image: Sidebar Nav Panel]

As you can see the navbar stretches from the very top to the very bottom of the web page. And this is done using CSS. Firstly here is the structure of my HTML (main code cut out for easier reading):

```html
<div id="app" class="app">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar-container"> </div>

    <!-- Header Nav Bar (holds logo) -->
    <div class="header-container"> </div>

    <!-- Menu that pops up when menu icon is pressed -->
    <div id="pop-up-menu" class="pop-up-menu-container"> </div>

    @yield('content')
</div>
```

I am using Laravel and this is why the `@yield('content')` line appears, this is called by my `v2_welcome.blade.php` file that looks like this:

```html
@extends('layouts.main')

<!-- Body Section -->
@section('content')
    <div class="landing-image-container">
        <!-- THIS HAS THE BACKGROUND IMAGE SEEN ON SCREEN -->
    </div>

    <div class="test">
        hey
    </div>
@endsection
```

The CSS for the sidebar looks like this:

```css
.sidebar-container {
    /* location */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
```

And my issue occurs when I insert any elements after the `landing-image-container` (i.e. the `<div class="test">`) as when I scroll down to see it this happens:

[image: Sidebar not sticking to position]

You can see the nav bar scrolls with the page, how do I get it to stick in position?

Thanks!

Comment: `position: sticky` or `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`, and if that makes the nav-bar hop over the background image / rest of the content you could place a wrapper around everything on the right and offset it to the right by the navbar's width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `position: fixed`, not with `position: absolute`.

```css
body {
  height:2000px;
}

.sidebar {
  background:blue;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As I thought, a simple solution haha, thanks @en0ndev !